# Prove that if f is diff. on $(-\infty,\infty)$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$,then there is a $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=2c$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I have been solving last exam questions of calculus course and encountered with a problem which I couldn't solve completely.The question is following;

> Determine whether the statement is true or false, and prove it;
>
> Suppose that f is differentiable function on $(-\infty,\infty)$ such that $f(0)=0$ and >$f(1)=1$,then there is a $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=2c$

My incomplete proof;

> Since it is diff. and cont. on $(-\infty,\infty)$, by Mean Value Theorem;
>
> $f'(r)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=1$, where $r\in(0,1)$
>
> Since for every f satisfying the conditions, there is $\exists r\in(0,1)$, and
> we want to prove that $\forall f$, there is $\exists c\in(0,1)$, so if I could establish a connection between r and c, I prove that the statement is true.

---

Everything up to now seems quite correct, but after that I continued like that;

> So, $f'(r)=f'(c)=1=2c$
>
> $c=1/2$

---

But it is obviously a wrong a answer since the functions $x,x^3,x^5..$ don't satisfy this property.In other words;

> $\frac{d(x^3)}{dx}|_{x=c=0.5}=3(0.5)^2\neq1$

So **what I am missing**, how can I improve this proof and is there any alternative proof other than what I have done?

Edit:Guys, I'm mainly interested in  **what I am missing in my proof**, the other questions are side questions.

Comment: You did not miss anything,you found that your approach is wrong, that there is no general relation between $r$ and $c$. You need a slghtly different approach as denoted in the answers, one conceptually before and one after the mean value theorem you used.

Comment: @LutzL but the fact that there is not general relation between r and c is not  proved rigorously, I just picked some function and tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-x^2$...

**Additional consideration:** For a continuous function $h$, finding a point $c\in(a,b)$ on an interval such that $f'(c)=h(c)$ equates to saying that $$g(x)=\int_a^x f'(t)-h(t)\,dt$$ has a stationary point in $(a,b)$. This gives you a trick to backwards-engineer a good candidate function for Rolle (though it can still be uninformative, since you have no guarantee that $g(a)=0\stackrel?=f(b)-f(a)+\int_a^b h(t)\,dt=g(b)$ ).

Comment: I didn't get it :)

Comment: Apply Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but as I pointed out in my question, I am mainly interested about what I am missing and how can I correct my proof .

Comment: Well, Lagrange says there is a point $r\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(r)=1$. Simply, it might be the case that this very special point does not satisfy $f'(r)=2r$. And there might not be any point $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=2c$ and $f'(c)=f'(r)$. Rolle/Lagrange/Cauchy hardly say anything about the points of which they garantee the existence (and for a very good reason).

Comment: As of what you were missing, I suggested it was the right idea: I don't think you can somehow reverse-engineer $f'(r)=f'(c)$. Best for you to know that you often need to guess the smart function to subtract from $f$ in order to get a sensible result through Rolle/Lagrange/Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

Starting reverse engineering from the quotient $\frac{f'(c)}{2c}$ one could also get the idea to employ the extended mean value theorem with $g(x)=x^2$ leading to
$$
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b^2-a^2}=\frac{f'(c)}{2c}
$$
and using $a=0$, $b=1$ and some $c\in(a,b)$.

Comment: How did you reach from you assumptions to the conclusion with Cauchy's MVT, I didn't understand.

Comment: Because $(f(1)-f(0))/(1^2-0^2)=1$.